# CSV export script running out of memory

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that exports a MySQL database to CSV format. The strange CSV format is a requirement for a 3rd party software application. It worked initially, but I am now running out of memory at line 743. My hosting service has a limit of 66MB.

My complete code is listed here. http://pastebin.com/fi049z4n

Are there alternatives to using `array_splice`? Can anyone please assist me in reducing memory usage. What functions can be changed? How do I free up memory?

Comment: Hi, please show the relevant parts of the code here. Posting Pastebin links *alone* is frowned upon (although they're useful as an addition sometimes).  Thanks!

Comment: Read and write in chunks. Also `66M` for the cli-interpreter is very low. There is usually no reason to limit the cli-interpreter at all. Talk to your hoster.

Comment: Are you trying to build the whole thing in memory?  Please show us some code or pseudo code.

Comment: Optimize your strategy like arkascha suggests. Then, also make sure to disable output buffering using `while(ob_get_level() > 0) {ob_end_clean();}` and `flush()` after each `fputcsv`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change your `CSV` creation strategy. Instead if reading the whole result from the database into an array in memory you must work sequencially:

- Read a row from the database
- Write that row into the `CSV` file (or *maybe* buffer)
- Free the row from memory
- Do this in a loop...

This way the memory consumption of your script does not rise proportionally with the number of rows in the result, but stays (more or less) constant.

This might serve as an untested example to sketch the idea:

```
while (FALSE!==($row=mysql_fetch_result($res))) {
  fwrite ($csv_file."\n", implode(',', $row));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have a link to an example of this? Or where can I read up on this technique?

Comment: I added a sketch of the suggested approach. No link at hand currently. Take care that you escape any delimiters contained inside the results members (`,`).

Answer (score 0):

Increase the memory limit and maximum execution time

For example :

```
// Change the values to suit you
ini_set("memory_limit","15000M");
ini_set("max-execution_time", "5000");
```

Comment: @Ben Carey Thanks for fixing the typo.

Comment: Yes, increasing the memory limit to 512MB fixed it, but it is only a temporary solution as the data will still increase by 100 fold.

Comment: Where do you put this?